# How to work around no inheritance with Enums?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have several finite list types that are coded as `enums` and they all look exactly like this, with the exception, of course, of actual values that vary from one enum to another:

```
public enum SomeType {

    TYPE_A("A", "Type A Description"),
    TYPE_B("B", "Type B Description"),
    TYPE_C("C", "Type C Description");

    private String key;
    private String label;

    private static Map<String, SomeType> keyMap = new HashMap<String, SomeType>();  

    static {
        for(SomeType type : SomeType.values()) {
            keyMap.put(type.getKey(), type);
        }
    }

    private SomeType(String _key, String _label) {
        this.key = _key;
        this.label = _label;

    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public static List<SomeType> getValueList() {
        return Arrays.asList(SomeType.values());
    }

    public static SomeType getByKey(String _key) {
        SomeType result = keyMap.get(_key);

        if(result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key: " + _key);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

IOW, they should all have the same constructor/format (`String _key, String _label`) as well as the methods and supporting Map for looking up by String.

Java enums do not support inheritance.  Is there a clever workaround whereby I can declare all of the repeated boilerplate in a single base class and then have the enums psudo-inherit them from there?

Comment: I guess you mean `public enum ReportType`?

Comment: What about generics?

Comment: it's not about extending them, it's about concentrating shared patterns in a single location rather than repeating them in each enum...

Comment: Sorry, then I retract my comment and close vote.

Comment: Actually, Java enums do support inheritance, just not in the form of one enum type extending another; what you *can* do is declare abstract methods in the enum type, which get implemented in each of the enum values; also, enum types can implement interfaces. But the real problem here, I suspect, is that enums are being misused, as "key" and "label" look like they could be the enum "name()" and "toString()" values; and instead of having a "getByKey(String)" method, use the enum values directly (they can be easily stored/recovered from JPA/Hibernate entities, for example).

Comment: @Rogério: _declare abstract methods in the enum type, which get implemented in each of the enum values_ - that would produce even more of boilerplate code, wouldn't it?

Comment: @wypieprz I only said that enums allow you to do that; in this particular case, I don't see a reason for it; in other cases, it can be extremely useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155405/java-enum-extends-workaround